# Changing Subtitles in Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, viewpagerindicator

Hi there I have been using the ViewPagerIndicator library for some time now and I want my action-bar's title to change every time the user swipes to another Fragment to the other pages here is the code I am thinking off but it is just not working.

```
Activity miz = getActivity();
    miz.setTitle("Miz");
```

I have put this code **in all my Fragments** displaying different titles every time but for some reason it is not working properly as it is always *late*. I think it may have something to do with the OnCreate , OnResume or OnPause and can not lay a finger on it can some one help ? I want the Title of the Action Bar to change while the next Fragment is visible to the user.

I have also though of some code like this

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Activity miz = getActivity();
    miz.setTitle("Miz");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular :

```
this.getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

With ActioBarSherlock :

```
this.getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

Comment: @Mizzeeboy What are you trying to actually do? When the tab switches you want the title of the ActionBar to change? Or do you wan the subtitle?

Comment: @Mizzeeboy I didn't down vote it but I should because you failed to communicate what you are trying to do to and what exactly is going wrong. Both Ahmad and I tried helping you and you are giving us attitude now? Go hit your head against the wall till you learn something because you clearly don't appreciate another's help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();  // or getSupportActionBar() for ActionBarSherlock
actionBar.setTitle("test");
```

In a Fragment:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();  
actionBar.setTitle("test");
```

Comment: Well with this code I get an error at the part where it says getActionBar this is probably cause I am in a Fragment not an Activity

Comment: I have tried the other method and I have imported the Library of ActionBarSherlock and I still cannot get it to work with the getSupportActionBar() as I get a red line

Comment: Nope this still doesn't work as I am putting this in Multiple tabs not just one. It sets the last one I code

Comment: Thanks for Down voting my answer just cause you can't answer it that's very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Miz");
```

It will work

Reference: [Setting a subtitle on my Toolbar from a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26880544/setting-a-subtitle-on-my-toolbar-from-a-fragment)