# How to set subTitle in CollapsingToolbarLayout android

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I need to set Title and SubTitle in my app. But In new design library using CollapsingToolbarLayout can able to set Title and scrolling with image is working fine. How to set the SubTitle in CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Comment: Having the same problem, looking desperately for an answer :((

Comment: Did you get a reference to the `Toolbar` in code, and set the `subtitle`? I tried it in my code, but it does not work; however, I am having other issues with my `CollapsingToolbarLayout` right now, and that might be why

Comment: When we try to set subTitle in Toolbar CollapsingToolbarLayout is not working. So we need to set the title and subTitle in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: have you found a solution for it?

Comment: Still not got any solution on this

Comment: No solution by far. And I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069107/how-to-show-toolbars-logo-icon-title-subtitle-when-wrapped-in-a-collapsingto) is more wide.

Comment: i think you have to try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26880544/setting-a-subtitle-on-my-toolbar-from-a-fragment) solution for `setTitle("")` and `setSubtitle("")` of toolbar

Comment: @pRaNaY I am not trying to set the subTitle in toolbar. I need to set subTitle in CollapsingToolbarLayout so that on scroll that text will scroll and collapse.

Comment: Try this answer from another thread with the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32220854/1665562

Comment: Any update for this case?

Answer (score 1):

We can set the Title and subtitle for Toolbar programmatically like this :

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.history));
    toolbar.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.month));
```