# How to show Toolbar's logo, icon, title, subtitle when wrapped in a CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

After **Android Support Design Library** was released, I wanted to implement an effect like a page of **Twitter Profile**, in which `Toolbar`'s `title` and `subtitle` could be changed as screen scrolled vertically. So I tried to use `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `Toolbar` from **Android Support Design Library** to achieve this effect. Everything worked as expected except that `Toolbar`'s content couldn't be showed or changed as I wanted. I should have been wanting to display `collapseIcon`, `navigationIcon`, `title`, `subtitle` of `Toolbar`, but they didn't show up even though I had set them in the layout and programmatically. Just as the [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) said,

> Note that in those cases, you should call setTitle() on the
>   CollapsingToolbarLayout, rather than on the Toolbar itself.

If you have checked the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html), you would find out `CollapsingToolbarLayout` only focus on settings of `title`, but can do nothing about `collapseIcon`, `navigationIcon` and `subtitle`.

So could someone tell me how to achieve this effect by `Toolbar` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`? If they couldn't be able, then what other things could be? Anybody has any ideas about this?

Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note. Android design library doesn't require android M preview.

Comment: I think this is what you're experiencing: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175069

Answer (score 2):

This issue was reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175069) as a bug. I have personally experienced this with one of my apps. Setting the `topMargin` for the toolbar works for me. As somebody commented on the bug report, here is the fix, as a function from the issue report.

```
private void fixApi21ToolBarBug(Toolbar toolbar){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT!=21) return; //only on api 21
    final int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    final int result = (resourceId > 0) ? getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId) * 2 : 0;
    final CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams params = (CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.topMargin -= result;
    toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

See the result here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. For me it was fixed by removing the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the layoutparameters. However, this will mean that the status bar will not be part of the collapsing Toolbar backdrop.